# Delete particular polygon of a mesh

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, data-blocks

I'm trying to do something with scripting in Blender 2.8.
I have an stl model of cube. It has 12 polygons (12 triangles). I access them by using:

```
cube = py.data.meshes["Cube.001"]
polygons = cube.polygons
```

In some loop i select some of polygons:

```
for polygon in polygons:
    if some_condition:
        polygon.select = True
```

How can i delete them using code? May be I'm doing something wrong? I'm new to blender, do not be angry for this silly question.

Comment: As i understood bpy.ops.mesh.delete can delete only 'VERT', 'EDGE', 'FACE', 'EDGE_FACE' and 'ONLY_FACE', but not MeshPolygons

Comment: Have you tried with 'ONLY_FACE'?

Comment: @lemon Now i tried, but it did nothing.